# Why the error asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

As data, I transmit a list of categories and then collect information on the page.
The code works fine if process about 5000 records.
Exceeding this limit results in a Timeout Error after some time.

I tried ClientTimeout in ClientSession, but the result remains the same. Tell me what the problem is.

**Code:**

```
from aiohttp import ClientTimeout
timeout = ClientTimeout(total=600)
START = time.monotonic()
start_time = time.time()
code_VEND_list = []

class RateLimiter:
    """Rate limits an HTTP client that would make get() and post() calls.
    Calls are rate-limited by host.
    https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/how-do-you-rate-limit-calls-with-aiohttp.html
    This class is not thread-safe."""
    RATE = 2  # one request per second
    MAX_TOKENS = 5

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.tokens = self.MAX_TOKENS
        self.updated_at = time.monotonic()

    async def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        await self.wait_for_token()
        now = time.monotonic() - START
        print(f'{now:.0f}s: ask {args[0]}')
        return self.client.get(*args, **kwargs)

    async def wait_for_token(self):
        while self.tokens < 1:
            self.add_new_tokens()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        self.tokens -= 1

    def add_new_tokens(self):
        now = time.monotonic()
        time_since_update = now - self.updated_at
        new_tokens = time_since_update * self.RATE
        if self.tokens + new_tokens >= 1:
            self.tokens = min(self.tokens + new_tokens, self.MAX_TOKENS)
            self.updated_at = now

async def fetch_one(client, i):
    url = f'https://example.com/product/{i}'
    async with await client.get(url) as resp:
        resp_text = await resp.text()
        bs0bj = BeautifulSoup(resp_text, 'lxml')
        code_EAN = re.sub('^\s+|\n|\r|\s+$', '',
                          bs0bj.find('div', {'class': 'item_'}).get_text())
        code_VEND_list.append(code_EAN)


def file_writher():
    income1 = pd.DataFrame({'Code': code_VEND_list})
    income_sheets = {'MySite-Base': income1}
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('./Test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    for sheet_name in income_sheets.keys():
        income_sheets[sheet_name].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    writer.save()

async def main():
    vendor_seorce = []
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Source.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    for vend_code in worksheet.col_values(0):
        vendor_seorce.append(vend_code)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as client:
        client = RateLimiter(client)
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_one(client, id_cat)) for id_cat in vendor_seorce]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    finish_time = time.time() - start_time
    print('Done!')
    print(f'Time: {finish_time}')
    file_writher()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**Error code:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\test\Stack.py", line 89, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "F:\Python\test\Stack.py", line 81, in main
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "F:\Python\test\Stack.py", line 52, in fetch_one
    async with await client.get(url) as resp:
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 544, in _request
    await resp.start(conn)
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 905, in start
    self._continue = None
  File "F:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 656, in __exit__
    raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

Comment: You set a timeout of 600s at the second line, which you then use in ClientSession. This will throw a TimeoutError when 600 seconds elapsed and the client did not finished.

Comment: I tried without the total = 600 parameter, the error repeats.

Comment: Found in the documentation:
"By default aiohttp uses a total 300 seconds (5min) timeout, it means that the whole operation should finish in 5 minute.
All fields are floats, None or 0 disables a particular timeout check, see the ClientTimeout reference for defaults and additional details."

I set total=0, test for an hour, it works fine. I'll let you know if something changes.